# Will Unity performance ever improve on older hardware?

Tags: unity

Despite tweaking, unity only runs 'acceptably' on my mid-to-lowendish laptop, despite being advertised otherwise. Are there improvements planned or am I better off getting used to xfce/lxde right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think unity will ever go into the direction of being a lightweight DE, so yeah i suggest you try out lxde or xfce. lxde is lighter but xfce is very light as well and has more features i believe, and both are perfect for laptops.